# How should I deal with an aggregated model in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am learning ASP MVC and I have problem. I have class Company with an aggregated property:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Address = new Address();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

And Address class:

```
public class Address
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

How should I write edit for this field? I have tried to create control AddressDetail and pass it to UiHint attribute on Address property, but in view i have additional Id property to edit (!?). When I hide it model state in post is not valid because this property is required. 
Another question is how should repository look like for Company? Should it use AddressRepository somehow or write Address by itself?

Maybe somebody have example of that kind of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the Address class has a parameterless constructor (like your company class), the default mvc modelbinder will have no problem handeling your object. It is not a problem, that both your Company class and Address class has an Id property.

MVC will by default assign your inputfields with names like 'Id' and 'Address.Id', which allows for the modelbinder to distinguish between the two properties.

You could register an editor template for your address class in Global.asax, or you could simple make a partial view and pass it Company.Address in your main view.

Comment: It is not as elegant as creating ViewModel, but for my simple objects I don't want to create huge class with mapping properties. Editor template is all I need. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I would classify the flat view model approach as more elegant. In my opinion, MVCs ability to serialize and deserialise custom property types recursively is one of the more awesome featues (although is most definitely does not have to be flat). 

However, using a view model may be benefitial in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

One way to tackle this would be to create a view model that combines these fields.  You can pass that to the view, and have your controller & repository handle converting it back into your business models.  For example:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

For another example, check out "Pattern 3" here: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I do. However, realize that the client could easily change the `Id` in the DOM element to an Id other than the one that is being updated and cause another company's information to be updated.  (which is why the `ID` should be handled by the route instead)

Comment: @Jim You should always have security to verify that the authenticated user has permission to edit an entity. Never trust data sent from the client.

Comment: @Ryan: That's the point I was going for. A lot of times, this can be handled by the database itself (customer:1, address:2) won't return results joining on (customer:1, address:20).  But I've seen a lot of code where values are bound directly to a domain model or pulled from a view model into a domain model with the assumption that the data is correct because it's one level further from the user.  That doesn't change the fact that it's still user-entered data.